# Assign names to subset of columns with paste0

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has three columns

```
  Col1|Col2|Col3
```

I want to merge the text "Table1" into only Col2 and Col3

```
names(df)<-paste0("Table1_",colnames(df[,c(2:3)]))
```

but I end up getting

```
 Table1_Col1|Table1_Col2|
```

The third column I get blank and no column name. I am trying to get

```
Col1| Table1_Col2| Table1_Col3
```

Comment: You need to specify the indices for `names` too, as shown in the answer by @diomedesdata. Otherwise you are assigning two values to three columns, which is why the third is NA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost had it:
`names(df)[2:3] <- paste0("Table1_", names(df)[2:3])`

Because a `data.frame` is a list of vectors, you can just use the simpler `names()` rather than `colnames()` (but both are completely fine imo).

Comment: The argument to `colnames` can also just be a vector: `names(df)[2:3] <- paste0("Table1_", colnames(df)[2:3])`.